# IE11 Frame Notification Bar - Click "Save"

Tags: excel, vba, notifications, frame, internet-explorer-11

I am stuck at a point in automating a process where I need to access the frame notification bar in IE11 - I have found the below code useful, but receive a "Type Mismatch" on the line

h = ie.Hwnd

Is it because I have declared IE as internetexplorermedium?

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Sub lime()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("http://xxx/")
Doodly ie
Muddly ie
Set doc = ie.Document

doc.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue").Value = "4"

doc.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('ctl32$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue','')", "JavaScript"

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

doc.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue").Value = "1"

doc.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl00").Click

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

doc.parentWindow.execScript "$find('ctl32').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML')", "JavaScript"

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))


Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h As Long
h = ie.Hwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke

End Sub

Sub Doodly(ie)
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
End Sub

Sub Muddly(ie)
Do While ie.busy
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I get no error when doing that right after Navigating

First step is to get it to compile - probably before you come here
Try this

Replace

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

With

```
  Dim ie As Object
```

Before

```
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: the project does not compile, I receive a "type mismatch" error on the line "h = ie.Hwnd", am I missing a reference or something? excel 2010

Comment: Did you type in `Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` manually - or does IntelliSense start offering you the SHDoc keyword as you type?

Comment: Probably explains why it doesn't compile -- updated my answer with a prelim suggestion

Comment: thanks, but I am accessing an intranet site and from prior research I need the "Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium" to have the code work. The code I had works all the way up to when the frame notification bar appears, up to where "Dim o As IUIAutomation" begins. any other ideas or can it not work with how I have defined ie?

Comment: Well. you're defining ie as multiple references and overwriting previous definitions- If you need multiple definitions then define them as multiple objects. You're basically overwriting what you originally set them to.  and now the error is at `Dim i as IUIAutomation`??

Comment: the error is in the same place as it was previously, the reason I mentioned "Dim i as IUIAutomation" is because that is the where the code I have added to existing code that already worked.